# Best way to working with existing database and non exist database in java spring boot

Tags: database, spring-boot, hibernate

I plan to build an application which will connect to existing database but it also has own new database, let's say the existing database on SQLSERVER(used by another apps) and the new database on POSTGRESSQL, the problem cases that i have are:

1. For new database I just can create entity model on spring for it and let hibernate generate to database table, but how about the existing one. Do I need to build entity from the existing database schema ? If i create from existing database to entity then someone directly alter on the table for other application purpose, it will make my application error. How to handle this case?
2. If I create entity based on each table in existing database it will takes time because the existing database is really big meanwhile I have to do a lot transaction on those existing table. Any other solution for this?

Comment: For the existing database you just need to map whatever tables you need to use, if you will use the whole DB then yes, you have to map it. 
Regarding someone else altering the tables, that is a control you need to put in place to be aware of any change and react accordingly.

Comment: @arturo.bhn How if I didn't map it to hibernate entity model for the existing database? And just do raw query inside my spring boot app to write or read to the table, is it possible?

Comment: yes, that is also posible. You will be completely handling everything manually though.

Comment: @arturo.bhn Any concern if I will handle raw query manually without map it to model entity? Like the performance or other things?

Comment: well, I don't know what is your technical requirement or your architecture so IMHO there is no concern on doing it manually.